# PHP session won't work after upgrade to PHP 5.6

Tags: php, session

Recently my hosting provider decided to upgrade from PHP version 5.4 tot version 5.6, and after that I experience a problem with sessions I'm using in my login system.

The login system is a simple one, after checking user name and password a session variable is set and the user is redirected to the protected page. Once there, it will be checked if the mentioned session variable is set or not to decide if the page has to be shown or if the user has to be redirected to the login page.

As suggested, up to a few days ago everything was working fine! However, when a user tries to log in now and is redirected to the protected page, he will be sent back to the login page, probably because of a problem with the session due to the PHP upgrade.

Below are some parts of the code.

```
<?php
//login page
session_start();
if ($check >= 1)
// If combination user name password is correct.
{
  session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
  header('Location: /');
  exit();
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
// protected page
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
// User not logged in.
{
  session_unset();
  if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
      $params["path"], $params["domain"],
      $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
  }
  session_destroy();
  header('Location: /login');
}
else
// Logged in, show page.
{
  // page
}
?>
```

Comment: Some code would greatly increase chances of figuring out what the issue is. Might very well be that you are using old functions that were removed in either 5.5 or 5.6.

Comment: Without seeing some code all you are going to get is **guesses** My guess is that your code is old and is using a removed session function like `session_register`. Paste some code quickly or this question will probably get closed

Comment: I added two parts of the code which may help.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, that should work fine. What do you get when you do `var_dump($check);` in the first code? You can also try to comment out the `header();` and do a `var_dump($_SESSION['logged_in']);` after it's supposed to be set to make sure it's actually being set. @TB308

Comment: Everything that has to do with the $check is working fine, as there is only a redirect when a correct combination is entered. When I try var_dump($_SESSION['logged_in']); the result is bool(true) which is correct. So it goes wrong getting that on the protected page.